# Binding to the href attribute in a link

Tags: data-binding, dart, dart-polymer, polymer

Why can I do

```
<img _src="/foobar/{{ cssPath }}.jpg">
```

but not

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" _href="{{ cssPath }}">
```

The first line replaces the path correctly. In the second line cssPath is null. Does anyone have an idea how to bind to a `link`'s href attribute or is that impossible?

Regards and Thanks
Robert

**EDIT**

Looks like my object gets constructed too late. I defined it globally like this: final themeManager = new ThemeManger._(); But it looks like this is happens too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `style` tag with an `@import` directive

```dart
this.shadowRoot.append(new StyleElement()..text = "@import url('some.css')");
```

Answer (score 4):

`<link rel="stylesheet">` is not support natively in shadow dom, but `<style>` is. Support stylesheets is a feature Polymer provides on top of the native stuff.

When the element definition is registered, Polymer inlines stylesheets into `<style>`. You can check this by examining the element' shadow dom in the devtools. This means bindings on the link's href won't work (everything is setup at registration time).

Something like this would be nice to support. I suggest filing a bug.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Looks like there is no realgood way except ^^ and /deep/ I will look more into this :)